# NotifyProperty not triggering

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I've got two buttons on the same page, one just below my gallery and one in a bottom navigation bar. Both commands trigger but the bottom one is broken. It never goes to my NOTIFYProperyChanged

```
  <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="IMAGES" XAlign="Start" YAlign="Center" Style="{StaticResource Labelfont}" TextColor="White"/>
                <Grid x:Name="ImageGallerys">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*">
                        </RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="128">
                        </RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto">
                        </RowDefinition>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Image 
                        Source="{Binding PreviewImage}" Grid.Row="0">
                    </Image>
                    <custom:ImageGallery ItemsSource="{Binding Images}" Grid.Row="1">
                        <custom:ImageGallery.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Image Source="{Binding Source}" Aspect="AspectFit">
                                    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.PreviewImageCommand, Source={x:Reference EditIssue}}" CommandParameter="{Binding ImageId}" />
                                    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                </Image>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </custom:ImageGallery.ItemTemplate>
                    </custom:ImageGallery>
                    <Button 
                        Grid.Row="2" Text="Photo" Command="{Binding CameraCommand}">
                    </Button>
                    <Button 
                        Grid.Row="2" Text="Pick" Command="{Binding PickCommand}">
                    </Button>
                </Grid>



<!--Bottom Navigation Bar-->
        <Grid Grid.Row="2">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="50" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackLayout x:Name="slButtons" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Spacing="5" BackgroundColor="White">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  BackgroundColor="#FBB040">
                <Button 
                    Grid.Row="2" Text="Pick" Command="{Binding PickCommand}">
                </Button>
            </StackLayout>
```

This is the method just before the NotifyProperty should be called.

```
public async Task ExecutePickCommand()
        {
            var file = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync();

            if (file == null)
                return;

            byte[] imageAsBytes = null;
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                file.GetStream().CopyTo(memoryStream);
                file.Dispose();
                imageAsBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
            }

            if (imageAsBytes.Length > 0)
            {
                var resizer = DependencyService.Get<IImageResize>();
                imageAsBytes = resizer.ResizeImage(imageAsBytes, 1080, 1080);

                var imageSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(imageAsBytes));
                _images.Add(new GalleryImage { Source = imageSource, OrgImage = imageAsBytes });
            }
        }
```

This is the Notifypropery part, it supposed to go into the method ItemSourceChange as it does with my first button, with the second button it just ends after.

```
 public static readonly BindableProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create<ImageGallery, IList>(
                view => view.ItemsSource,
                default(IList),
                BindingMode.TwoWay,
                propertyChanging: (bindableObject, oldValue, newValue) => {
                    ((ImageGallery)bindableObject).ItemsSourceChanging();
                },
                propertyChanged: (bindableObject, oldValue, newValue) => {
                    ((ImageGallery)bindableObject).ItemsSourceChanged(bindableObject, oldValue, newValue);
                }
            );

        public IList ItemsSource
        {
            get
            {
                return (IList)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty);
            }
            set
            {

                SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value);
            }
        }

        void ItemsSourceChanging()
        {
            if (ItemsSource == null)
                return;
        }


        void ItemsSourceChanged(BindableObject bindable, IList oldValue, IList newValue)
        {
            if (ItemsSource == null)
                return;

            var notifyCollection = newValue as INotifyCollectionChanged;
            if (notifyCollection != null)
            {
                notifyCollection.CollectionChanged += (sender, args) => {
                    if (args.NewItems != null)
                    {
                        if (args.NewItems.Count > 0)
                        {
                            foreach (var newItem in args.NewItems)
                            {
                                var view = (View)ItemTemplate.CreateContent();
                                var bindableObject = view as BindableObject;
                                if (bindableObject != null)
                                    bindableObject.BindingContext = newItem;
                                _imageStack.Children.Add(view);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _imageStack.Children.Clear();
                        foreach (var Item in ItemsSource)
                        {
                            var view = (View)ItemTemplate.CreateContent();
                            var bindableObject = view as BindableObject;
                            if (bindableObject != null)
                                bindableObject.BindingContext = Item;
                            _imageStack.Children.Add(view);
                        }
                    }
                    if (args.OldItems != null)
                    {
                        // not supported
                    }
                };
```

I discovered if I did this, it finaly calls notifyproperty like in the upper button. But it crashes now due to nullreference error in this button, as it seems to create Another instance or something?

```
<custom:ImageGallery ItemsSource="{Binding Images}" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="ImageGalleryss">
                        <Button 
                        Grid.Row="3" Text="Pick" Command="{Binding PickCommand}">
                        </Button>
                </custom:ImageGallery>
```

Comment: Is `_images` a `ObservableCollection`?

Comment: Yes "        ObservableCollection<GalleryImage> _images = new ObservableCollection<GalleryImage>();"

Comment: The weird thing is that it works with the button in the local grid, but the button in the bottom navigation bar triggers but notifyproperty doesn't

Comment: It doesn't work anywhere outside the local grid, so maybe it is the custom gallery that is needed?